# Hidden surface removal

Tags: python, mesh, workflow

I have a blender scene with several overlapping identical objects. Is there a simple way to determine and export visible faces given a specific viewpoint. 
That is, i want to use Blender for hidden surface removal.

If there is a better way to do this, with some other tool, please share as well.

Comment: By specific viewport, do you mean a camera or the actual Blender viewport and its virtual "camera"?

Comment: Its virtual camera.

Comment: Do you want to delete every face which is invisible to the camera (faces on the back side of the model will be deleted)? Or do you want to merge faces which are overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by select everything with box select (<kbd>B</kbd>), circle select (<kbd>C</kbd>), or lasso select (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>) while in solid view with *Limit selection to visible* enabled, then inverting the selection (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) and deleting faces:

[image]