# How can I select only the front facing polygons of an object?

Tags: python, scripting

### I want to select the front face, but I don’t want to select the back face

```
bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(xmin=0,xmax=area.width,ymin=0,ymax=area.height,wait_for_input=False,mode='SET')
```

[image]

### actual：

[image]

### hope：

[image]

How to ignore the back?
The backside culling is useless.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to hide backface? Do you want to remove them from selection?

Comment: @Crantisz I want to select the front face, but I don’t want to select the back face

Comment: It looks like you have x ray mode on.  What happens if you use `bpy.ops.view3d.toggle_xray()` just before you do the select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select the front-facing faces of the selected object.

Conditions :

- You must be in OBJECT mode.
- Your object must be a MESH object.
- You workspace must contain at least a 3D viewport editor.

You'll have to learn a bit about the dot product : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

```
import bpy
import mathutils

mesh = bpy.context.object.data  # Retrieve the mesh
normals = [p.normal for p in mesh.polygons]  # Compute polygon normals

# Compute the view direction
up = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
view3d_area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.ui_type == 'VIEW_3D')
trans_world = (view3d_area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_matrix.inverted()).to_3x3() @ up
trans_world.normalize()

# Unselect the mesh elements
for v in mesh.vertices:
    v.select = False
for e in mesh.edges:
    e.select = False
    
for i, normal in enumerate(normals):
    # Select the front facing faces
    mesh.polygons[i].select = trans_world.dot(normal) >= 0
```

[image]

Related [Automated way to make "Select interior faces" ignore select faces that are visible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57540/automated-way-to-make-select-interior-faces-ignore-select-faces-that-are-visib)

Comment: Might require either converting view vector to local space of mesh, or face normals to global space https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119342/15543  Similarly could use angle test (which is basically dot prod anyhow) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96066/how-to-get-all-faces-based-on-a-certain-angle-of-their-normals

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the heads-up you're right ! I didn't take that into account